# Cakephp: how to access data from database with 3 model and 1 controller

Tags: php, database, cakephp, view, controller

I'm trying to access the data from my db as my title describes my structure I have 3 model and 1 controller,
my problem is I'm not sure in which function i should put the ff:

FruitsController:

```
$this->set('apples', $this->Apple->find('all'));
$this->set('oranges', $this->Orange->find('all'));
$this->set('bananas', $this->Banana->find('all'));
```

so that I can access them in the view/see their data(what's inside them) using this method:

```
<?php pr($apples); ?>
<?php pr($oranges); ?>
<?php pr($bananas); ?>
```

tnx and appreciate all the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this in Controller class's function.. [Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel)

```
$this->loadModel('Apple');
$this->loadModel('Orange');
$this->loadModel('Banana');
```

Or you can add to controller.. [Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses)

```
public $uses = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana');
```

After that you can define

```
$this->set('apples', $this->Apple->find('all'));
$this->set('oranges', $this->Orange->find('all'));
$this->set('bananas', $this->Banana->find('all'));
```

and you can use it in view files...

Answer (score -2):

If you want to load the model to get data only for a particular function then you can use loadModel in that function. it will ensure that the model is loaded only when the function is called amd will be available only within the function.

```
$this->loadModel('Apple');
$this->loadModel('Orange');
$this->loadModel('Banana');
```

where as

```
public $uses = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana');
```

will make the model available throughout the controller but will increase the loading time of the controller.
also if you just want the records of the table and not the associated tables it will be a good practice to set recursive=-1